# Using dict like C switch

Tags: python-2.7

```
class checkevent:
def __init__(self,fromuser):
self.fromuser = fromuser

def openid_check(self):# use sqlalchemy
    exist_user = User.query.filter_by(openid = self.fromuser).first()
    if exist_user is None:
        text = u'请绑定后在使用'
        return text

def grade(self):
    openid_check()
    exist_user = User.query.filter_by(openid = self.fromuser).first()
    geturp = urp(exist_user.username, exist_user.password_urp) #the function
    return geturp  #return the grades as text
def key_check(self,x):   # use dict like switch
     {'grade': self.grade
      }  
contents = checkevent('ozvT4jlLObJWzz2JQ9EFsWSkdM9U').key_check('grade')
print contents
```

It's always return None,I want to get a value
and it's the right way to use dict?

Comment: `def key_check(self,x)` doesn't return anything. That's why you get `None`. Plus you don't use the `x` in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `return` statement in `key_check`, so naturally it doesn't return anything. You're basically missing the last bit of the implementation: once you look up the appropriate function by name, you need to call that function and return the result.

```
def key_check(self, key):  # "x" is a meaningless name; use something meaningful
    lookup = {
        'grade': self.grade
    }
    func = lookup[key]  # Look up the correct method
    return func()  # Call that method and return its result
```

---

Technically you could in-line all that into one statement if you really wanted to, but unless performance is at a premium I wouldn't recommend it as the readability suffers.

Comment: another questions , why I can not call the openid_check() in grade function ,and why the dict use like {'grade':self.grade} instead of {'grade':grade}

Comment: `openid_check` and `grade` are both *instance methods*, so you need to call them on an instance (`self`). If you have more questions on that, it's a whole other topic with plenty of resources available online (just Google "python instance method").